# Prepend a marker string in front of each line of another program's output, while preserving aligned tab-formatted tables

Tags: python, unicode, vertical-alignment, ansi-escape, tabstop

I have a program that prints tab-formatted output. (SO renders tabs below as spaces, in question edit mode it is tabs.)

```
Some Key:       Value
Another:        Different value
```

When I run this program as subprocess, I intentionally prepend `>:` in front of every line, to distinguish what is my output and what is coming from the subprocess. Problem is, prepending these two chars sometimes breaks the column alignment.

```
>: Some Key:        Value
>: Another:     Different value
```

Is there a way to preserve the alignment while adding few characters in front of the lines? Ideally, I would want not to introduce tabs to outputs that originally did not contain tabs. Also, I am printing the output line by line as the subprocess is running, so in the beginning I might not yet know if it will produce tabs or not.

I looked at Unicode, if there is some magic hiding there, and found nothing likely.

I also investigated the TBC control sequence https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/csi_sg/. My outputs go into Jenkins build console, so I can plausibly use ANSI control sequences.

Comment: I guess SO provided an answer, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386647/so-renderer-breaks-makefile-syntax ;P Replace all tabs with 4 spaces when printing the outputs, "to make code in the snippets looks well for everyone". Adding a prefix then does not break formatting. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.expandtabs

Comment: End your prefix with a TAB. That will cause everything to re-align to the next tab stop.